# Getting tight asymptotic upper and lower bounds of product logs

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

Consider

$$ E(n)=\log_2\left(\log_2 (4)\right) +\log_2\left(\log_2 (5)\right)  ... \log_2\left(\log_2 (n)\right) $$

This is equal to

$$E(n)= \log_2\left(\log_2 (4)*\log_2(5)*\log_2(6) ... \log_2(n) \right) $$

I want to find the two tightest possible functions A, B such that

$$ A(n) = O(E(n)) , E(n) = O(B(n))$$

For a basic start I noted that

$$E(n) \le log_2(4) + log_2(5) ... log_2(n) \le log_2(2) + log_2(3) ... log_2(n) \le log_2(n!)  = O(n \log(n))$$

And clearly

$$1 + 1 + 1 ... 1 \  (n \ times) < E(n)$$

Thus
$$ n = O(E(n)), E(n) = O(n \log(n))$$

But I want to get a much tighter bound than this. I hypothesize that

$$E(n) = O(n \log(\log(n))$$

But a method of proof escapes me at the moment. Any ideas??

Comment: Seeing the relationship of the Gamma function to Stirlings approximation to deriving $O(n!) = O(n \log n)$ I have decided to add a complex-analysis tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sum $E(n)$ is a Riemann sum for an integral of an increasing function; in particular,
$$
\int_3^n \log_2(\log_2 x)\,dx < E(n) < \int_4^{n+1} \log_2(\log_2 x)\,dx.
$$
The function $\log_2(\log_2 x)$ has a nearly elementary antiderivative (that can be found by integrating by parts):
$$
\int \log_2(\log_2 x)\,dx = x\log_2(\log_2 x) - \frac{\mathop{\rm li}(x)}{\log 2},
$$
where the logarithmic integral li$(x)$ is defined by
$$
\mathop{\rm li}(x) = \int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}.
$$
Therefore
$$
n\log_2(\log_2 n) - \frac{\mathop{\rm li}(n)}{\log 2} + O(1) < E(n) < (n+1)\log_2(\log_2 (n+1)) - \frac{\mathop{\rm li}(n+1)}{\log 2} + O(1),
$$
which easily implies
$$
E(n) = n\log_2(\log_2 n) - \frac{\mathop{\rm li}(n)}{\log 2} + O(\log\log n).
$$