# Asymptotic bounds of product of $\log(i)$

Tags: asymptotics

$$\prod _{k=2}^n\left(\log_2k\right)$$

Can somebody help me with bounds of this expressions. I see only the rude measure:

$$\log_2n\le \prod _{k=2}^n\left(\log_2k\right)\le \left(\log_2n\right)^n$$

Comment: It will suffice to find bounds for the log of your product, $\sum_{k=2}^n \log_2 \log_2 k$, which is done at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084665/getting-tight-asymptotic-upper-and-lower-bounds-of-product-logs?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but I have a multiply and there is a sum, isn't it different for the both situations ?